# Finding length and angles of a triangle

Tags: java

My job is to compute the following properties of a given triangle: lengths of all sides, angles at all corners, the perimeter and the area. I have a Triangle class and a Triangle tester class. I THINK I have coded the perimeter and area correctly? But I am beginning to think instead of setting a constant variable side for my perimeter I should be using the lengths of all sides to find my perimeter as well. What I am stuck on is finding the lengths and the angles. For some reason when I run my tester class they all come out as 1.0. Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        /**
         * Variables
         */
        double x1;
        double x2;
        double x3;
        double y1;
        double y2;
        double y3;
        double lengthA;
        double lengthB;
        double lengthC;
        double angleA;
        double angleB;
        double angleC;
        double area;
        double perimeter;
        double base;
        double height;
        double p;

        /**
        Constructs x and y coordinates
        @param x1, x2, x3 to x1, x2, x3
        @param y1, y2, y3 to y1, y2, y3
     */
     public Triangle(double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3)
     {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.x3 = x3;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.y3 = y3;
     }

        /**
         *Find lengths of all sides
         */
        public double getLengthA()
        {
            lengthA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2));
            return lengthA;
        }

        public double getLengthB()
        {
            lengthB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y3 - y2), 2));
            return lengthB;
        }

        public double getLengthC()
        {
            lengthC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x3), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y3), 2));
            return lengthC;
        }

        /**
         * Find angles at all corners
         @return angles at all corners
         */
        public double getAngleA()
        {
            angleA = lengthA + lengthB + lengthC - (lengthB * lengthC);
            return angleA;
        }

        public double getAngleB()
        {
            angleB = lengthB + lengthA + lengthC - (lengthA * lengthC);
            return angleB;
        }

        public double getAngleC()
        {
            angleC = lengthC + lengthA + lengthB - (lengthA * lengthB);
            return angleC;
        }


        /**
         * Constant Variables
         */
        public Triangle()
        {   
            base = 5;
            height = 15;
        }

        /**
         * Find perimeter of triangle
         */
        public double getPerimeter()
        {
            perimeter = lengthA + lengthB + lengthC;
            return perimeter;
        }

        public double getHalfPerimeter()
        {
            p = perimeter / 2;
            return p;
        }

        /**
         * Find area of triangle
         */
        public double getArea()
        {
            double area = Math.sqrt(p * (p - lengthA) * (p - lengthB) * (p - lengthC));
            return area;
        }
}
```

Here is my tester class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class TriangleSimulator 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


 String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter X coordinate for the first corner of the triangle: ");
 double x1 = Double.parseDouble(input);
 input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Y coordinate for the first corner of the triangle: ");
 double y1 = Double.parseDouble(input);
 input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter X coordinate for the second corner of the triangle: ");
 double x2 = Double.parseDouble(input);
 input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Y coordinate for the second corner of the triangle: ");
 double y2 = Double.parseDouble(input);
 input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter X coordinate for the third corner of the triangle: ");
 double x3 = Double.parseDouble(input);
 input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Y coordinate for the third corner of the triangle: ");
 double y3 = Double.parseDouble(input);

 Triangle t = new Triangle(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3);

 System.out.println("Length A is: " + t.getLengthA());
 System.out.println("Length B is: " + t.getLengthB());
 System.out.println("Length C is: " + t.getLengthC());
 System.out.println("Angle A is: " + t.getAngleA());
 System.out.println("Angle B is: " + t.getAngleB());
 System.out.println("Angle C is: " + t.getAngleC());
 System.out.println("Area: " + t.getArea());
 System.out.println("Perimeter: " + t.getPerimeter());

 in.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're showing JOptionPanes that prompt the user for input, but you're **not getting the input** and you're thus not using the input to set the state of your Triangle, creating a default Triangle object using its parameterless constructor. Understand that there's no magic in Java programming, and your Triangle object will not magically know what numbers the user has entered and change itself accordingly. Instead **you** must give that information into your Triangle.

What you must do is assign the results returned from the JOptionPanes, parse them into doubles, and then use those numbers to create a Triangle, using the constructor that takes numeric value parameters, not the default constructor.  Do this, and you should be good.

e.g.

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter X coordinate for the first corner of the triangle: ");
double x1 = Double.parseDouble(input);
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Y coordinate for the first corner of the triangle: 
double y1 = Double.parseDouble(input);
//.... etc repeat...

Triangle triangle = new Triangle(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3);
```

---

**Edit**

This constructor ignores the values being passed in:

public Triangle(double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3)
{
    x1 = 0;
    x2 = 0;
    x3 = 0;
    y1 = 0;
    y2 = 0;
    y3 = 0;
}

A constructor like the one you'll need, should take the values passed in, and use those values to set class fields.  For instance here:

```
public class Foo {
   private int bar;  // the bar field

   public Foo(int bar) {
      this.bar = bar;
   }  
}
```

Note that I use `this.bar` above so that Java knows that I want to set the bar field with the value held by the bar parameter (the bar **without** the `this`). You will need to do something similar only with 6 parameters, not one.

Then you do all your calculations in a separate block of code called an **initializer block**:

```
{ 
    /**
     * Find lengths of all sides
     */
    lengthA = Math.pow(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2) * .05, lengthA);
    lengthB = Math.pow(Math.pow((x3 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y3 - y2), 2) * .05, lengthB);
    lengthC = Math.pow(Math.pow((x1 - x3), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y3), 2) * .05, lengthC);
}
```

This code gets called **before** your constructor, and so even if you set your Triangles fields correctly, this code wouldn't work. You don't want to use initializer blocks, and you can forget I even mentioned them other than to tell you not to use them. Instead do your calculations **inside your constructor**, and do so **after** setting all your fields.

Note that I've purposely not posted a solution to your problem because I firmly believe that what most of us need is to understand the concepts underlying any problems we are having, and then use that understanding to create our own code solutions.

Most important, read your texts, no better, **study** your texts, because the mistakes you're making involve foundational concepts, and show that you don't yet understand these concepts and have resorted to guessing. This will never work, as you need to understand all this and understand it well if you're going to be able to progress in this course.

Good luck!

---

**Edit 2**
For Tom, run this:

```
public class TestInitializerBlock {
   public TestInitializerBlock() {
      System.out.println("Inside of constructor");
   }

   {
      System.out.println("Inside of initializer block");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new TestInitializerBlock();
   }
}
```

Comment: I have made my changes once again. Now my calculations come out as 0.0

Comment: @Courtney You should use your new methods. For example this `System.out.println("Length A is: " + t.lengthA)` should be updated to `System.out.println("Length A is: " + t.getLengthA())`.

Comment: I did that. Now all lengths and angles are 1.0, perimeter is 3.0 and area is 0.0. I have entered multiple numbers each run and still the same calculations.

Comment: @Courtney: this looks very fishy: `lengthA = Math.pow(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2) * .05, lengthA);`. Multiplied by 1/2 and then the product raised to the lengthA power?? Re-think your math and your logic.

Comment: That was the calculation I found to find lengths of a triangle? Is this not the correct way to find these calculations?

Comment: @Courtney:  you simply use the calculation of the length of any line with 2 known end points. sqr root of (delta-x squared + delta-y squared). You would never raise anything to the length power. You need to think through what you're doing logically.

Comment: @Courtney Don't forget that `lengthA` is still `0` if you call `getLengthA()` the first time. Therefore you're calculating `Math.pow(x, 0)` which returns `1`. And `angleA = lengthA = lengthB + lengthC - (lengthB * lengthC);` doesn't look good, too. Are you sure, that you want to set `lengthA` to the same value as `angleA`?

Comment: @Tom I guess I have my formula wrong to find each length. I think it is supposed to be angleA = lengthA + lengthB - (lengthB * lengthC); does that sound better?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am currently looking up a better formula to find my lengths as that one is obviously wrong. Oops. I'm currently a student and new to all this Java coding.

Comment: Okay I have edited my original code post. Take a look. When I run my program everything seems to be calculated good except my area is always -0.0. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Courtney About your `area`: I have an idea why it is currently wrong, but since you're new to programming, you need to find the solution yourself :P. I will give you this hint: look at your formular and think about every used variable in it and if that variable is set correctly at the time you're calling `getArea();`.

Comment: @Courtney I'm not sure whether you're still working on this.  I guess I'm rather late to the party.  But the formula you quoted for the angles (four comments above this one) is not correct.  To figure out the angles once you have the lengths, you need something called the "cosine rule" or "cosine law".  I suggest you google this.